# Send daily email alerts of the Bitcoin Price

Tags: python, python-3.x, email

My script sends daily alerts of the bitcoin price to my inbox. I am using CoinDesks API, and the following libraries:

[requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)==2.18.4

[schedule](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)==0.5.0

and gmail sender: https://github.com/paulchakravarti/gmail-sender

Here is my code:

```
"""Send daily Bitcoin price alerts to inbox."""
from time import sleep

from requests import get
import schedule
from gmail import GMail, Message


def get_bitcoin_price():
    """Get current Bitcoin price in USD using Coindesk's real-time API"""
    response = get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json').json()

    return response['bpi']['USD']['rate']


def send_email(recipient: str='walid.mujahid.dev@gmail.com'):
    bitcoin_price = get_bitcoin_price()

    # enter actual password, otherwise, nothing happens.
    gmail = GMail('Price Alert <walid.mujahid.open@gmail.com>',
                  password='password')
    message = Message(f'Bitcoin is at {bitcoin_price} right now!',
                      to=recipient,
                      text=f'The current Bitcoin price is {bitcoin_price}.')

    gmail.send(message)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    schedule.every().day.at("06:30").do(send_email)

    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        sleep(1)
```

Comment: How/when do you run a script like this? Im learning but I assume you run the .py and just keep the IDE open? It's not a "run and done" type program, right?

Comment: @BruceWayne I would not keep it running through the IDE, rather I would open up the terminal and keep it running. To be honest, though, this specific script was made as a demonstration, I just wanted to see what could be improved. If were going to set it up for real, I would do so on [here](https://m.do.co/c/4827df313cae) and use `nohup`.

Comment: It's amazing how few lines of code this is

Comment: Instead of embedding the scheduling logic into the script, you could schedule your script from cron.

Comment: Is, by any chance, your real email address? Sure, one could guess it from your username but now that it is in a SE post surely somebody will start sending you spam.

Comment: Enjoy Python, @Keatinge :)

Comment: I suggest you also to build with almost the same code and Flask a simple webservice that feeds an Android Widget (like Universal Widget)

Comment: @Bakuriu Yes, they actually are my real email addresses, but I do not really worry about them because they are not my "main" ones. The dev one is already out there as I advertise it as my "dev" email. The .open email I just made for this script so I do not have to use any of my existing ones.

Comment: @Pitto That is a very interesting idea, I think I might do that.

Comment: I have just rolled-back your last edit. Don't update the code in the current question based on the received answer but rather, ask a new one. For more info read [this](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1763/for-an-iterative-review-is-it-okay-to-edit-my-own-question-to-include-revised-c)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

#### Define some constants

I'd make some constants and put them at the top of the program because if your program becomes bigger, it'll be harder to change their values:

```
EMAIL_TIME = '06:30'
SLEEP_TIME = 1
URL = 'https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json'
```

---

#### Never store your credentials in clear-text

Here, you replaced your actual password with a placeholder, but what if you mistakenly commit&push it to your public git repository? More, at the moment I can also take your email and send those nice Viagra emails.

What I usually do is store my credentials in a different config file which is in .gitignore as well (it's not A LOT safer, but at least you can't see them + it adds an extra layer of security anyways).

As an alternative, you can create environment variables to store them there if you'd like.

---

#### Error handling

Try to add some exception handling to let the user know if something went wrong with its script. You can even create your own exception class:

```
class RetrieveUrlException(Exception):
    pass
```

Which you can then call like this:

```
...
raise RetrieveUrlException('The URL could not be accessed')
```

Comment: I think it's a big assumption that "you replaced your actual password with a placeholder". It wouldn't surprise me at all if this "open" account has that password.

Comment: Indeed :) It wouldn't be a surprise

Answer (score 16):

It seems to me that running a specific command at a specific time each day is more the job of a `cron` daemon than of said command. As such, I would simplify the executable part of the script to:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    send_email()
```

and add an entry in your `cron` configuration that read something like

```
30 6 * * * /usr/bin/env python /path/to/your/script.py
```